# Два Foreign key в одной таблице. Автоматическое обновление DataGridView

Tags: c#, sql, сервер, ado.net

Добрый день. Вопрос заключается в следующем:
Есть 3 таблицы - Data, History, TypeHistory. Data и TypeHistory - две независимые таблицы, а History зависит от этих двух таблиц по внешнему ключу. Тоесть у History есть два foreign key. 
Создаю DataSet, который содержит все эти таблицы, и создаю 3 DataGridView на основе этих таблиц. Мне нужно, чтобы когда я перемещался по строкам в DataGridView, который привязан к TypeHistory, или перемещался по строкам в DataGridView, который привязан к Data, происходила автоматическая выборка в DataGridView, который привязан к History, на основе внешних ключей.
Я знаю, что если было бы две таблицы, к примеру только Data и History, то такую автоматическую выборку можно было сделать так:
В property(свойствах) контролла DataGridView, который привязан к History, в поле DataSourse передать dataBindingSource(от таблицы Data), а в поле DataMember передать "FK_History_ToData", тоесть foreign key, который создавался при создании таблиц. Все! И никакого кода. После этого, при переходе между строками в DataGridView, привязанному к Data, меняется автоматически представление на соответствующее в DataGridView, привязанному к History.
Как быть с 3-мя таблицами, которые я описал выше?

Знает кто нибудь?

Comment: Нужно менять привязку грида History в зависимости от того, какой грид сейчас в фокусе.

Comment: От этого не будет толка, так как там привязка по двум Источникам данным должна проходить, а не или по тому или по тому. Одновременно по двум

Comment: Приведите пример кода, заполняющего эти datatable (не из БД, а вручную). И нарисуйте примеры датагридов, какие данные должны отображаться.

Comment: Короче записал видео, как и что я хочу увидеть, тоесть таблица History зависит от двух внешних ключей, и мне нужно заполнять информацией DataGridView только той, которая зависит от таблицы Data и TypeHistory по внешнему ключу. Вот видео [ссылка](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-ff1xPNZYNM&feature=youtu.be)

Comment: Кто нибудь поможет?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Набил код создания и заполнения таблиц сам. Если не совпадает с вашим - не обессудьте.

Вот полностью рабочий пример. Используется привязка данных. И нужна лишь пара строк кода в событии для изменения фильтра. В итоге содержимое третьего грида зависит от выделенных строк в первых двух.

```
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            //InitializeComponent();

            Size = new Size(500, 600);

            var dtData = new DataTable("Data");
            dtData.Columns.Add("id", typeof(int));
            dtData.Columns.Add("value", typeof(string));
            dtData.Rows.Add(1, "data1");
            dtData.Rows.Add(2, "data2");

            var dtTypeHistory = new DataTable("TypeHistory");
            dtTypeHistory.Columns.Add("id", typeof(int));
            dtTypeHistory.Columns.Add("value", typeof(string));
            dtTypeHistory.Rows.Add(11, "type1");
            dtTypeHistory.Rows.Add(12, "type2");

            var dtHistory = new DataTable("History");
            dtHistory.Columns.Add("id", typeof(int));
            dtHistory.Columns.Add("FK_Data", typeof(int));
            dtHistory.Columns.Add("FK_TypeHistory", typeof(int));
            dtHistory.Rows.Add(101, 1, 11);
            dtHistory.Rows.Add(102, 1, 12);
            dtHistory.Rows.Add(103, 2, 11);
            dtHistory.Rows.Add(104, 2, 12);

            var ds = new DataSet();
            ds.Tables.Add(dtData);
            ds.Tables.Add(dtTypeHistory);
            ds.Tables.Add(dtHistory);
            ds.Relations.Add("FK_History_ToData", dtData.Columns["id"], dtHistory.Columns["FK_Data"]);
            ds.Relations.Add("FK_History_ToTypeHistory", dtTypeHistory.Columns["id"], dtHistory.Columns["FK_TypeHistory"]);

            var flp = new FlowLayoutPanel { Parent = this, Dock = DockStyle.Fill };
            var dgvData = new DataGridView { Parent = flp, Width = 400 };
            var dgvTypeHistory = new DataGridView { Parent = flp, Width = 400 };
            var dgvHistory = new DataGridView { Parent = flp, Width = 400 };


            var bsData = new BindingSource();
            bsData.DataSource = ds;
            bsData.DataMember = "Data";

            var bsTypeHistory = new BindingSource();
            bsTypeHistory.DataSource = ds;
            bsTypeHistory.DataMember = "TypeHistory";

            var bsHistory = new BindingSource();
            bsHistory.DataSource = bsData;
            bsHistory.DataMember = "FK_History_ToData";

            dgvTypeHistory.SelectionChanged += (s, e) =>
            {
                string id = dgvTypeHistory.CurrentRow.Cells["id"].Value.ToString();
                bsHistory.Filter = "FK_TypeHistory = " + id;
            };

            dgvData.DataSource = bsData;
            dgvTypeHistory.DataSource = bsTypeHistory;
            dgvHistory.DataSource = bsHistory;
        }
    }
}
```

В вашем видео какой-то комбобокс фигурирует. Я не стал вникать в нюансы. Но не сложно добавить изменение фильтра `BindingSource` по событию изменения комбобокса.